# Hamming spheres

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I have the following task with hamming spheres. Need to get some feedback on my idea? Don't know if it is correct can't find much information on it.

Let $C$ be a code of length $n$ and distance at least $d$. For $w$ in $K^n$, let $B_w(r)=\{w'  \in K^n \mid d(w,w`) \leq r \}$

1. For a codeword $v$ in $C$ show that $B_w(d-1) \cap C = \{v\}$

So $C \cap B_v(t) \neq \emptyset $ iff $t(C) \leq t $ so in this case $ t(C) = \frac{d-1}{2}$ and $ t=\frac{d-2}{2}$  so $t(C) \leq t $ is never possible, so the statement is false?

Don't know if this is 100% correct? - found that in [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/BAG/vol.42/no.2/b42h2qui.pdf)

1. Show that there exists a code $C$ of length $n$ and distance at least $d$ such that 
   $ max_{length(C) = n,  d(C) \geq d} \mid C\mid \leq \frac{2^n}{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + ...+\binom{n}{d-1} }  $

any hints how to bite the second question?

Comment: I guess in the first question, $w$ should be $v$, and in the second question, the "there exists a code $C$ length $n$ and distance at least $d$ such that" should be removed. Furthermore, what is $K$? (I guess it is the binary alphabet $\{0,1\}$.)

Comment: Furthermore, in your attempt to solve the first question, you probably forgot about the precondition that $v$ is a **codeword**.

Comment: Your second question has the inequality reversed: there exists a code of blocklength $n$ and minimum distance $d$ with at least as many codewords as $$\frac{2^n}{\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{d-1}}.$$ For a solution to the correct version of your second question, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/504773/15941). Azimut's answer, which you have accepted, is incorrect on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that the statements of both questions are not stated entirely correct.
I'm going to answer the following.

1)

> For a codeword $v$ in $C$ show that $B_v(d-1)\cap C = \{v\}$.

Let $w\in B_v(d-1)\cap C$. Then $d(v,w) \leq d-1$. Since $v$ and $w$ are codewords of the code $C$, and $C$ has minimum distance at most $d$, it follows that $v = w$.

2) I guess you want to show the *sphere packing bound* (aka *Hamming bound*):

> For any binary code $C$ of length $n$ and minimum distance $d$,$$\lvert C\rvert \leq \frac{2^n}{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \ldots + \binom{n}{t}}$$
>   where $t = \lfloor (d-1)/2\rfloor$ is the number of errors the code $C$ can correct.

Let $K = \{0,1\}$ and $w\in K^n$.
The number of words in distance $d'$ to $w$ is $\binom{n}{d'}$, since this is the number of choices for the differing positions (the entries are fixed then).
This shows $\lvert B_w(d')\rvert = \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} + \ldots + \binom{n}{d'}$.

Since $C$ has minimum distance $d$, the Hamming balls $B_v(t)$ about the codewords $v$ are disjoint. So in the ambient Hamming space $K^n$, there may not exist more that $$\frac{\lvert K^n\rvert}{\lvert B_v(t)\rvert} = \frac{2^n}{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \ldots + \binom{n}{t}}$$
such Hamming balls.

Comment: _Why_ are the Hamming spheres of radius $d-1$ centered at the codewords _disjoint_ for a code of minimum Hamming distance $d$? Your last statement says that a $[7,4,3]$ code cannot exist since the maximum number of codewords is no larger than $$\frac{2^7}{1 + \binom{7}{1}+\binom{7}{2}} = \frac{128}{1+7+21} = 4.4\cdots$$ But this is patently false since the $[7,4,3]$ Hamming code exists.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: True, thank you. That's the result of mechanically writing without thinking. I've modified my answer. Given all the glitches in the question, it's hard to tell what the OP really wanted. Either I (still) got his question right, or it is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504773.