# showing a code exists given the lower bound of its dimension (with respect to its length and distance)

Tags: combinatorics, cryptography, coding-theory

How do I show that there exists a code $C$ of length $n$ and distance at least $d$ such that 
 $ max_{length(C) = n,  d(C) \geq d} \mid C\mid \geq \frac{2^n}{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + ...+\binom{n}{d-1} }  $?

My intuition is I have to use a corollary derived from the gilbert-varshamov bound theorem that says:

$\mid C\mid \geq \frac{2^{n-1}}{\binom{n-1}{0} + \binom{n-1}{1} + ...+\binom{n-1}{d-2} }  $

and somehow exploit the fact that $\binom{y}{x} = \binom{y-1}{x-1} + \binom{y-1}{x}$ but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: I wrongly put a close vote for a duplicate. Sorry.

Comment: @azimut Click "close" again and it will offer you to retract the vote. I'm not sure if there is a time limit, though, but if that happens, edit a post a bit (i.e., change the first formula to display style) and the time for the limit will probably reset.

Comment: @VedranŠego: Ah, right. Didn't remember that. Vote is retracted now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working with binary vectors.

$\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{d-1}$ is the the number of vectors at Hamming distance strictly less than $d$ from the vector at the center.  It is the volume of
the Hamming sphere of radius $d-1$. Thus,
$$D = |C|\left[\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{d-1}\right]$$
is the *sum* of the volumes of all the Hamming spheres of radius $d-1$ centered at the
$|C|$ codewords. Note that $D$ is an *overbound* on the *total*
number of vectors in these spheres
because some of the spheres overlap each other
since their surfaces are at distance $1$ from neighboring codewords at distance
$d$, and so we are double-counting a lot. 
But, if $D < 2^n$, then there *must* exist vectors
that are  not in any of the spheres, and so are at
distance $d$ or more from *all* the codewords in $C$. 
**Find** one such vector that is not in any of the Hamming spheres
and include it in $C$ to create a new code $\hat{C}$. Note that
$|\hat{C}| = |C|+1$. Now, calculate 
$$\hat{D} =|\hat{C}|\left[\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{d-1}\right]$$ and check whether $\hat{D} < 2^n$. If so, the
same argument as above applies and we can add one more codeword to
$\hat{C}$.  Thus, augmentation of the code with one new
codeword being added at each step can continue until we 
have a code $\tilde{C}$ for which 
$$\tilde{D} =|\tilde{C}|\left[\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{d-1}\right] \quad \mathbf {\geq} \quad 2^n.$$
At this point, the above argument cannot be used
to say that we are *guaranteed* that there are more
vectors available to be added to $\tilde{C}$; there probably
*are* such vectors still available
because $\tilde{D}$ grossly overestimates the total volume of the
sphere, but this argument does not allow us to assert their existence.
But, no matter, we have constructed a code $\tilde{C}$ for which
$$|\tilde{C}| \geq \frac{2^n}{\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{d-1}}.$$
Note that this is a *constructive* argument in that there is a prescription
for how to find $\tilde{C}$ but it is not a very useful prescription in that
we have to search for a vector that is not in any of many Hamming spheres,
and there is no help provided to make this search efficient.

*But, but, but*, you argue, we began with a code $C$ of minimum distance
$d$. How can we be sure that such a code exists? That's easy: assuming that
we are not doing something nonsensical like starting with $d > n$,
the code $C = \{000\cdots 00, 111\cdots1000\cdots 00\}$ (where the
second codeword has Hamming weight $d$) is a code of minimum distance
$d$ that can serve as our starting point.

Comment: So your point is, I can argue about equality (basically where the hamming bound intersects with the inequality above)?

Comment: The Hamming bound does not "intersect" with the inequality, whatever is meant by that wording. Notice the difference between $t$ and $d-1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this completely... you mean we cannot actually prove it but there might be such a code, right?

Comment: See the amended answer which shows that we prove that such a code exists and have a prescription for how to go about finding it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It's very clear to me now.